# Amsmath and tikz - conflict?

Tags: amsmath, expansion, incompatibility, pgfmath

I have a problem with:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(1<0, "100","$\sin(x)$")}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
 ./MinimalConflit_amsmath.tex:9: Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
 <inserted text>
 \par ** l.9 ...thparse{ifthenelse(1<0, "100","$\sin(x)$")}
 \pgfmathresult
```

But the code is ok if I don't load the amsmath package. Is there a "conflict" with amsmath and TikZ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package re-defines `\sin` (and other operators) in a way that makes it fragile. The easiest solution would be to robustify `\sin` with the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package’s macor `\robustify`.

If you want to use [`pgfmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath) with other operators (and the ones (properly) created by `\DeclareMathOperator`) as well, you can generally robustify `\qopname` that is internally used:

```
\robustiy\qopname
```

If you can’t fully predict the input to [`pgfmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath)’s macros you can use `\pgfmathIfthenelse` defined as

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathIfthenelse#1{\pgfmathifthenelse{#1}{1}{0}%
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax\expandafter\pgfmath@firstoftwo
   \else\expandafter\pgfmath@secondoftwo\fi}%
\makeatother
```

which isn’t as flexible for math parsing but works best for TeX/text.

As a compromise, use `\noexpand` (that’s a one-time protection), though you need three of them.

From the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=529), p. 529:

> `"x"`
>
> These operators are used to quote *x*. However, as every expression is expanded with `\edef` before it is parsed, macros (e.g., font commands like `\tt` or `\Huge`) may need to be “protected” from this expansion (e.g., `\noexpand\Huge`). Ideally, you should avoid such macros anyway. Obviously, these operators should be used with great care as further calculations are unlikely to be possible with the result.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\qopname
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathIfthenelse#1{\pgfmathifthenelse{#1}{1}{0}%
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax\expandafter\pgfmath@firstoftwo
   \else\expandafter\pgfmath@secondoftwo\fi}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfmathprint{ifthenelse(1<0, "100","$\sin(x)\cos(y)\tan(z)$")}

{\pgfmathprint{ifthenelse(1<0, "100","\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\ttfamily (x)")}}

\pgfmathIfthenelse{1<0}{\texttt{tt}}{\textsf{sf}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\robustify\qopname` you make all those operators survive the `ifthenelse`, and also the newly defined ones with `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: @egreg That is a good idea, of course.